# Creating numerical year column from a numerical month column

Tags: r

Here is a dataframe with a numerical `month` column. I took `month` as an example but I would appreciate the solution to be applicable to any quantities (without relying on the lubridate package).

```
tibble(month = seq(1:120))
```

How can I create a `year` variable starting from 1 and increasing by 1 every 12 months?

Here is an example of a desired output. With an ideal situation where the number of months is a multiple of 12 to use `rep` easily.

```
tibble(month = seq(1:120)) %>% 
       mutate(year = rep(1:10, each = 12))


# A tibble: 120 × 2
   month  year
   <int> <int>
 1     1     1
 2     2     1
 3     3     1
 4     4     1
 5     5     1
 6     6     1
 7     7     1
 8     8     1
 9     9     1
10    10     1
# … with 110 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "bag variable"?

Comment: Do you mean `mutate(year = ceiling(month / 12))`

Comment: @DarrenTsai using modulo  `mutate((month - 1) %% 12 + 1)`

Comment: @Mark I think what you mean is the integer division (`%/%`), not modulo (`%%`). I.e. `mutate(year = (month - 1) %/% 12 + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `findInterval` - I left your manual `year` just to check, and created `year2`:

```
df <- tibble(month = 1:120,
             year = rep(1:10, each = 12))

df$year2 <- findInterval(df$month, seq(1, nrow(df), 12))
```

Output:

```
    month year year2
1       1    1     1
2       2    1     1
3       3    1     1
...
13     13    2     2
14     14    2     2
15     15    2     2
```

This would work even if the months were out of order:

```
set.seed(123)
df2 <- data.frame(month = sample(1:120, 120))
df2$year <- findInterval(df2$month, seq(1, nrow(df), 12))

#     month year
# 1      31    3
# 2      79    7
# 3      51    5
# 4      14    2
# 5      67    6
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `cumsum` on `%% 12` modulo 12, need to add `+ 11` to January.

```
cumsum((df$month + 11) %% 12 == 0)
 #  [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
 # [25]  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
 # [49]  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6
 # [73]  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8
 # [97]  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(month = 1:120, year = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-120L))
```

Comment: if using `cumsum` then `cumsum(month %% 12 == 1)` should suffice. No need to add 11 etc